# Would Newton have understood that rockets would work in space?

Tags: space-travel

Goddard famously was ridiculed in the New York Times about rockets not working in the vacuum of space. Here we see that he theorized that rockets in fact would work in a vacuum: [https://www.nasa.gov/missions/research/f_goddard.html#:~:text=Goddard%20began%20teaching%20physics%20in,air%20in%20order%20to%20fly](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/research/f_goddard.html#:%7E:text=Goddard%20began%20teaching%20physics%20in,air%20in%20order%20to%20fly).

But would not Newton have been familiar with gunpowder rockets and also understood that they would work in the vacuum of space? Or did people not realize that space was nearly a vacuum and the question would not even have come up? Or perhaps rockets were so limited in their performance at Newton's time that they idea of using a rocket to reach space would not have occurred to Newton? I am pretty sure he did imagine a cannon firing a projectile into orbit but that is very different than attempting to reach, for example, the moon in this way and also is not rocket propulsion.

Comment: Please outline where you have looked for answers. Goddard was certainly *not* the first. The [Wikipedia article on Tsiolkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky) states:  *Starting in 1896, Tsiolkovsky systematically studied the theory of motion of rocket apparatus. Thoughts on the use of the rocket principle in the cosmos were expressed by him as early as 1883, and a rigorous theory of rocket propulsion was developed in 1896. ... by means of a multistage rocket fueled by liquid oxygen and liquid hydrogen* "

Comment: The question did not come up. Newton's preferred means of reaching the "outer space" (or, at least, Earth's orbit) was a launched projectile, see [Newton's cannonball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cannonball). Same as Jules Verne's two centuries later in From the Earth to the Moon. [Norton](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41374031) ascribes "*the first reference to jet propulsion as a direct means of locomotion*" to Gravesande's *Physices Elementa Mathematica* (1720), subtitled *Introductio ad Philosophiam Newtonianam*. But Newton had other preoccupations by then.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. People during Newton's era, and later, did not know that outer space was a near vacuum. The concept of an [aether/ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories) in space as a transporting medium for light was prevalent amongst many European scientists until it was proven that such an aether/ether did not exist. The composition of such an aether/ether was also uncertain.

As for Isaac Newton,

> Isaac Newton suggests the existence of an aether in the Third Book of Opticks (1st ed. 1704; 2nd ed. 1718): "Doth not this aethereal medium in passing out of water, glass, crystal, and other compact and dense bodies in empty spaces, grow denser and denser by degrees, and by that means refract the rays of light not in a point, but by bending them gradually in curve lines? ...**Is not this medium much rarer within the dense bodies of the Sun, stars, planets and comets, than in the empty celestial space between them?** And in passing from them to great distances, doth it not grow denser and denser perpetually, and thereby cause the gravity of those great bodies towards one another, and of their parts towards the bodies; every body endeavouring to go from the denser parts of the medium towards the rarer?"

The emphasis is mine.